# Спектральный анализ wav файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, нейронные-сети, фурье, wav

Доброго времени суток. Необходимо написать скрипт на Python 3, который будет считывать данные wav файла, вычислять спектр, передавать полученный спектр на вход нейронной сети для дальнейшей обработки. Если с чтением wav файла и нейронной сетью все понятно, то с расчетом спектра возникли проблемы. Может кто сталкивался с дискретным преобразованием Фурье на Python?

Comment: А в чем именно проблема с преобразованием Фурье? Оно есть в SciPy - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.fft.html

Comment: Если правильно помню, то fftw библиотека имела биндинги.

Comment: [Вот пример](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23378284/5741205)

Comment: Спасибо за пример!